# Windows service showing a GUI when no user is logged in

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, windows-services

Is it possible to a display dialog window from a windows service over the logon screen of Windows 7 (when no user is logged in yet) ?

I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/SubvertingVistaUAC.aspx) explaining how to display a window on a logged in user desktop but how to do it when there is no user logged in ?

I was thinking about trying to automatically log in a user then display the window on his desktop but is it possible to display it directly over the logon screen ?

Comment: Whatever it is you think you want to do, you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: Our client wants an alert to be displayed when a certain event occurs even when no user is logged in. If the client wants it, I'm trying my best to do it. But you may be right, another way is to try to change his mind...

Comment: It's not going to happen. If nobody is logged in then you've got no chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GINA was replaced by Windows Vista Credential Provider.

One of the [samples](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b1b3cbd1-2d3a-4fac-982f-289f4f4b9300&displaylang=en) (SampleHardwareEventCredentialProvider) does exactly what I want: display a window over the Logon UI and works with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is not an easy way to do this, I'm sure with some really convoluted PInvoke you might be able to accomplish something, but in all reality, I'd look at your system in general, showing dialogs from a Windows Service to a user is typically frowned upon.

Comment: You might have been able to do something with GINA but it's not possible now.

Comment: Yep, seems like "GINA DLLs are ignored in Windows Vista.".Thanks

Comment: The death of GINA is not mourned